# How do I process array data from a multiple-select field in a form, using Sequelize

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, sequelize.js

I have a simple form containing three fields (which correspond to three database columns): member_id, event_id and event_date.  The form utilises Formik to capture what the user enters and stores it as key/value pairs in a standard Formik variable, which Sequelize then posts to the database.

Member_id is a multiple-select input field, and when multiple options are selected, it passes an array of key:value pairs for that field to the Formik variable.  These key/value pairs are nested, so the output from the form when console logged looks, for example, like this:

[image: Screenshot]

In my table, I want this to create two rows, containing the following data:

```
    event_date:"20030203", event_id:"1", member_id:"1"
    event_date:"20030203", event_id:"1", member_id:"2"
```

I think the Sequelize bulkCreate method might be the correct way to post this to my database, but that method appears to rely on the data being formatted without a nested array I'm getting from my form.  Based on documentation here, 'Creating in Bulk' section: [docs link](https://sequelize.org/docs/v6/core-concepts/model-querying-basics/)

My question is, what is the normal way to approach this scenario - is it to rearrange the data Formik is giving me into one row per selected member ID, then use bulkCreate to post those many rows?  Or is there some other method I should be using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I went with a solution of rearranging the data Formik was giving me into one row per selected member ID, then used bulkCreate to post those many rows to the database.